# two optimizers in tensorboard (tensorflow graph)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

In tensorboard I see two adam (optimizer) nodes inside my graph, while I'm calling grads on this module only once (using the optimizer).
I don't see this behaviour in other nodes, and I can't understand why there are two adam nodes, or where does the other one is being used.
The process however, works as expected.

```
def sep_conv_ker(inputs):
    input_shape = inputs.get_shape().as_list()
    inputs_flatten = tf.reshape(inputs,[-1,1,input_shape[-2], input_shape[-1]])
    filter = tf.get_variable("filter",shape=[1, input_shape[-2], input_shape[-1], 1],initializer=tf.initializers.truncated_normal)
    sep_conv2d = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(inputs_flatten, filter, [1, 1, 1, 1], "VALID",
                                        name="sep_conv_cut_point")
    cut_points = tf.reshape(sep_conv2d,[input_shape[0],input_shape[1], sep_conv2d.shape[-1]])

    return cut_points
```

and the graph displayed in tensorboard
[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39765786/2904614) may answer your question.